# restkit JSON ios - putObject - send type info

Tags: json, ios, rest, types, put

i m using restkit on ios, and trying to use the putObject method
i m able to use it and send data with this format:

{"name":"Wet shirt night at Marquee","id":1,"idIcon":1,"note":78,"description":"connard","url":0}

however my web service is expecting something like:
{"event":{{"name":"Wet shirt night at Marquee","id":1,"idIcon":1,"note":78,"description":"connard","url":0}}

see the difference, the type name "event" at the beginning

do you guys have any idea how to set up restkit to send the object type name with the object data?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

solution:

RKObjectMappable.m

RKObjectMappableGetPropertiesByElement

return a dictionary with
object: your mapped dictionary
key: your type name